# Show popup and redirect to the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have been looking in too many links but I am not getting the desired results, although it is a very basic question to ask but i am unable to find some useful help.
I have a `hyperlink` pointing to the external link like `<a href="google.com" target="_blank">google</a>`,
Now I want to show a popup when somone clicks on this link, I can fire up a `jquery modal` or `fancybox` on `onclick` event, thats not the problem.
I assume that it is not possible to show my own window on external link?
I need to fire up a modal and after closing of modal, the external link should be opened in new tab.Thanks for help.
I don't know what code to share here as i have only `hyperlink`

Comment: So are you saying you want something like a preview pop-up window and then when the user closes that preview/pop-up it opens that link in a new tab?

Comment: well that popup stays for say 5 seconds and then external link is openned in new tab

Comment: What I understood is: you have a page with link to google.com.  once the user click the link you want to show a pop-up and after closing it, you want to open the google.com page.  is that right?

Comment: What is in the popup though? I mean, what does the popup look like?

Comment: yes @SULTAN you are right but link must be loaded in new tab

Comment: @greetification it shows some message with thanks message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting you right, solution

in your home page add the link to the popup window

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('new.html');">Open</a>
```

in the popup window add the following link

```
<a href='http://google.com' onclick='window.close();' target='_blank'>LINK</a>
```

if it is not what you want, I hope it is a starting point to the solution

Comment: well it is near to what I want, there is a link and window is clicked when I click on the link, i need to automatically close the window